# Execute result of previous command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to script update my remote.origin.url from https to git

I came up with this

```
IN=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
arrIN=(${IN//@/ })
echo "git@"${arrIN[1]} | bash -s git remote set-url origin
```

My echo line seems to display correct

```
git@bitbucket.org:bh/app.git
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`-s` tells bash to read commands from stdin. Not arguments to commands you've given on the command-line, but full commands. It ignores any command on the command-line.

```
$ echo 'echo test command' | bash -s 'echo this command is ignored'
test command
```

You don't need `bash -s`. You can just append the string you want to the `git remote set-url` command.

```
git remote set-url origin git@"${arrIN[1]}"
```